# Insertion Sort not working properly

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

```
package sort;

public class InsertionSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] input ={5,3,5,3,2,1}; // the input to be sorted.
        int key; // the value that will be put into its place in the pass
        int j = 0; // indexes to be 
        int i = 0; // used for sorting


        for(j = 1; j < input.length; j++){
            key = input[j];
            for(i = j-1; i >= 0; i--){ // Look for a proper place for the key
                if(i-1 < 0){
                    if(input[i] > key){ // Have you found that place ?
                        for(int k = j;k > i; k--){ // Begin shifting
                            input[k] = input[k-1];
                        } // Done Shifting
                        input[i] = key; // Insert the key in proper place
                        break;
                    }
                }else{
                    if(input[i] > key && input[i-1] < key){ // Have you found that place ?
                        for(int k = j;k > i; k--){ // Begin shifting
                            input[k] = input[k-1];
                        } // Done Shifting
                        input[i] = key; // Insert the key in proper place
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for(int each : input){
            System.out.println(each);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that if my input has repeated numbers, sorting fails.

For `int[] input ={5,3,5,3,2,1};`, I get `1 2 3 5 5 3`
For non-repeated numbers, sorting works fine.

What is wrong here ?

Comment: Hi. Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Sorry if I asked a question that fell out of the rules. I did post an SSCCE, though :) +1 for pointing it out

Comment: This is an over complicated insertion sort, I would recommend shortening it to prevent errors.

Comment: @JamesFazio uhm... how ??? :) I am doing it on my own so this is what I came up with

Comment: I would recommend drawing the problem out on a piece of paper, it helps to clear out unneeded code

Comment: @JamesFazio The idea is to get an alternative perspective on the code. I did sketch it out on paper and this is what I came up with :)

Comment: hmmm why don't you just use `Arrays.sort();`

Comment: @MrD because I am self-studying from MIT OCW and first lecture was on Insertion Sort

Comment: **Fixed** A classic bug caused by confusion between `<` , `<=` and `>` and `>=` Now sorting works well on repeated numbers, too

Comment: The problem is a boundary condition where you have > and you need >=. If you work out the example by hand you will find it.

Comment: @user814064 Thank you for your response. Yes, you are right. I messed it up with boundary condition :)

Comment: And if this is overly complex, what is a simpler way out ? :)

Comment: @Little Child It is my honest oppinion arrays are a waste of time. In the real world you just use lists and forget about these kind of issues. Problems with arrays are usually related to indexes. There is no real value on fixing problems like that. Specially when you can figure them out in notime with the debugger

Comment: @MrD Yes, I don't disagree with you but since I am taking an algorithms class, I need to know how this works. In few days' time I will bother you guys with sorting linked lists, if that would not be too much of a hassle :D

Comment: @MrD: Using containers instead of arrays does not magically eliminate boundary-case issues.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth not entirely but they are much more practical and you know it

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I wasn't asking to spot error, perse. I thought my logic was horribly wrong.

Comment: @MrD: Indeed.  But I'm not sure that's really relevant here ;)

Comment: Have faith LittleChild - if your logic was horribly wrong you likely wouldn't have been able to get that far.

Comment: @BobbyDigital True but a properly crafted sorting algo should work in all input conditions and that is why I thought it was all wrong.

Comment: True - there's no doubt you had issues, or you wouldn't be here, but there's a big difference between an oversight and not being able to logically "sort" out what's going on.

Comment: @BobbyDigital The issue with self study is that I do not have an instructor to go to when I have problems :)

Comment: @LittleChild: This is the perfect opportunity to learn to debug ;)  Find the simplest test-case you can, and then literally step through line-by-line until it stops behaving as you expect (you'll need to figure out what you expect on paper, etc. first, of course).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth That is what I did. I tried a worst case scenario of `10...1` and they were sorted out properly. Then, I tried random combination and then boom .... error. 
yes, I did it on paper first :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] input = {12, 21, 21, 1, 4, 5, 66, 74, 0, -2, 5, 3, 5, 3, 2, 1}; // the input to be sorted.
    int key; // the value that will be put into its place in the pass
    int j = 0; // indexes to be 
    int i = 0; // used for sorting

    for (i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
        key = input[i];
        j = i;
        while (j > 0 && input[j - 1] > key) {
            input[j] = input[j - 1];
            j--;
        }
        input[j] = key;
    }

    for (int each : input) {
        System.out.println(each);
    }
}
```